# Algorithm of CSS3 filter blur

Tags: algorithm, css, blur

[Doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur()_2) describes that filter blur applies a Gaussian blur to the input image. I have compared it with [OpenCV's GaussianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#gaussianblur), but their effect are not same.

I want to implement the same effect with CSS3 filter blur. Where can I find the algorithm?

Comment: I'm afraid the only way is to download the browser's source code. Most browsers (the ones that matter at least) are open source.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of parameters that you can tweak on a Gaussian filter. Knowing that is a Gaussian filter is only half the solution..

You will need to know the size of the filter (3x3, 5x5, or any odd number combinations), the Gaussian standard deviation of the Gaussian in each axis(although i think it should be symmetrical)

You need to know and implement those parameters to your Gaussian filter in order to get the same effect.